# How does a smooth differential structure hide a discontinuity?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

A theorem of differential topology states that any $C^1$ manifold admits a compatible $C^{\infty}$ differential structure.  I find this curious on account of such manifolds as the graph of $f(x) = x|x|$, which is $C^1$ but has a discontinuity it it's second derivative.

**Question**: How does the compatible smooth structure on the above graph "hide" the discontinuity?

A qualitative answer is fine.

Comment: That manifold is $C^1$-diffeomorphic to the real line.

Comment: @Pedro Interesting.  But by the same reasoning I would think that a $C^0$ manifold which is $C^0$ diffeomorphic (i.e. homeomorphic) to a $C^{\infty}$ manifold would thus also inherit a $C^{\infty}$ structure from the diffeomorphism, which is false.  What differs between the $C^0$ and $C^1$ cases?

Comment: No, that is not true. You can pull back the smooth structure under a homeomorphism to get a smooth structure on the domain. Then with this smooth structure, our homeomorphism is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: I don't think "hiding" the discontinuity is the right metaphor. It's more that you're simply removing some charts from the atlas, in fact a LOT of charts, but you're doing so in a verrrrry careful manner, so that what's left is a $C^\infty$ atlas.

Answer (score 4):

I think a better way to think about it is that a $C^1$ manifold doesn't "know" about any discontinuity in higher derivatives it might have.  You can't define the second derivative of a function on a $C^1$ manifold, so you can't even express the idea that such a derivative would be discontinuous intrinsically.

Let's call your example $X$.  Note that the projection map $p:X\to\mathbb{R}$ sending $(x,x|x|)$ to $x$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism.  So actually, $X$ is exactly the same as $\mathbb{R}$ as a $C^1$ manifold.  The $C^1$ manifold structure of $X$ can't tell that it has a "kink" at $(0,0)$: as far as the $C^1$ structure is concerned, $X$ might as well just be $\mathbb{R}$ with no kink.

The only reason you think that your $X$ has a kink in it is because you are imagining it sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^2$, and indeed the map $X\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is not a $C^2$ embedding.  But this embedding is not part of the $C^1$ manifold structure of $X$.  The $C^\infty$ structure you can put on $X$ doesn't "hide" the singularity of $X$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$; it's just that the map $X\to\mathbb{R}^2$ fails to be a $C^\infty$ embedding.